# Informatica : Not able to connect to Integration Service

Tags: windows

I am new to informatica and looking for assistance from available experts.

I am able to login to admin console (http://localhost:6008/administrator/#admin) where I can see my node is available, my repository service is available, my integration service is available.

Through Power center desiner tool, I am able to view my mappings. Also, I am able to connect to Powercenter Workflow manager. However, while trying to execute my workflow, it says that cannot connect to integration service.

I am getting following error in log :

CCM_10322

The following error occurred while logging to Log Service: [[DOM_10022] The master gateway node for the domain is not available. 
Electing another master gateway. Wait for the election of the master gateway node to  complete. 
If the problem persists, verify that the master gateway node is running.].

Thanks,
  Manish.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-requisites: 
1)Once the Repository files has been restored make sure all service(rep & IS services) are up.
2)Make sure the INFA_DOMAIN_FILE env variable has been created and has the right values. And make sure file with path added in the PATH, in both server & client machines.

Solution :Last resort, Upgrade the domain info in server & Client machines as shown below, then restart the infaservices & server. Now it works!!!

Upgrade the Domains:

`Cd $INFA_HOME/isp/bin`

`Sh infacmd.sh updateGatewayInfo –dn Domain_name –dg Servername.net:6005`

in server:

`Cd $INFA_HOME/isp/bin`

`Sh infacmd.sh updateGatewayInfo –dn Domain_name –dg Servername.net:6005`

in client:

`cd e:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\PowercenterClient\CommandLineUtilities\Pc\server\bin\`

`infacmd updateGatewayInfo –dn Domain_name –dg servername.net:6005'

Restart the Server: 
`Cd $INFA_HOME/tomcat/bin`

`Sh infaservices.sh shutdown`

`Sh startserver.sh shutdown`

`Sh startserver.sh startup`

`Sh infaservices.sh startup`

Done. Now check!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must define one node as Master Gateway using `infacmd` or `infasetup` then you can run all services from admin console.